# Search function special character bug

Tags: jquery

My function works just fine until you input a special character like (,+,-,},...
Then my page starts to lag and the items displayed "twinkle" (They appear=>disappear=>appear=>...). What can I do to forbid entering any special character value?

```
function showList(id) {

    var level = $('#charLevel').val();
    var name = $('#gearName').val();
    var timer;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'list.php',
        type: 'get',
        data: { 'slot': id, 'level': level, 'name': name },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#list').html(data);

            $('#gearName').keyup(function() {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                var ms = 300;
                timer = setTimeout(function() {
                    showList(id);
                }, ms);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Edit :

Here is the modal content code :

```
<input id="gearName" type="text" placeholder="Search..."/>
<table class="tableau">
    <tr>
        <td width="10%" class="top">L</td>
        <td width="90%" class="top">Name</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="scroll" id="list">
</div>
```

Here is the list.php code :

```
$slot = intval($_GET['slot']);
$level = intval($_GET['level']);
if(isset($_GET['name'])){
    $name = $_GET['name'];
}
else {
    $name = '';
}

$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM item WHERE level <= :level AND name like :name ORDER BY level DESC");
$result->execute(array(':level'=>$level, ':name'=>'%'.$name.'%'));
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

echo '<table>';

while($row = $result->fetch()){
    echo '<tr onclick="itemInfo('.$slot.','.$row->id.',0)">';
        echo '<td width="10%">'.$row->level'</td>';
        echo '<td width="90%">'.$row->name.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

And the showList function is called by the following :

```
$('#S1').on({
    mouseover: function(){
        $('#head').show();
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        $('#head').hide();
    },
    click: function(){
        modalContent(1);
        showList(1);
    }
});
```

Comment: try to encode your string like this, `encodeURIComponent(level)`..

Comment: @user26409021: No need, jQuery does that when you provide an object for `data` as the OP is.

Comment: Do not attach event handlers in callbacks. You will have several handlers for an event.

Comment: @undefined is correct, it gets slower and "laggy" because you attach more and more handlers, so the function is calling itself until it's almost an endless loop.

Comment: What is the `data` returned from server like? Is it containing the `level` or `name` input by user?

Comment: @gildor : The data returned is a list of item stocked in the database. They have a level and a name. I use the id to know which div is going to contain the item information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see anything to suggest that `+` or similar are the issue, but you really don't want to be re-hooking `keyup` every time you call `showList`. Just hook it up **once**:

```
function showList(id) {

    var level = $('#charLevel').val();
    var name = $('#gearName').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'list.php',
        type: 'get',
        data: { 'slot': id, 'level': level, 'name': name },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#list').html(data);
        }
    });
}
function hookUpId(id) {
    var timer = 0;

    $('#gearName').keyup(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            showList(id);
        }, 300);
    });
}
```

...and start by calling `hookUpId(relevantValueHere);`.

---

In the comments below, you've said that `gearName` is *replaced* by the code. But according to the HTML in your question, it isn't:

```
<input id="gearName" type="text" placeholder="Search..."/>
<!--   ^---------------------------------------------------- Here's '#gearName' -->
<table class="tableau">
    <tr>
        <td width="10%" class="top">L</td>
        <td width="90%" class="top">Name</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="scroll" id="list">
<!--                ^--------------------------------------- Here's '#list' -->
</div>
```

Your code is updating `#list`; that doesn't replace `#gearName`.

---

You've said you *have* to hook it up in `showList`, but that isn't the right place to do it. You've said putting the code to hook it up at the end of the HTML doesn't work, but fundamentally, it does. Here's a full example with `setTimeout` standing in for `$.ajax`: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/lalun/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="gearName" type="text" placeholder="Search..."/>
<table class="tableau">
    <tr>
        <td width="10%" class="top">L</td>
        <td width="90%" class="top">Name</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="scroll" id="list">
</div>
<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";
    function showList(id) {

      var level = $('#charLevel').val();
      var name = $('#gearName').val();

      // Simulate ajax with setTimeout
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#list").html(
          '<table>' +
          '<tr onclick="itemInfo(\'stuff here\')">' + // Note that I didn't bother to include itemInfo, so clicking won't actually do anything
          '<td width="10%">random level: ' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + '</td>' +
          '<td width="90%">some name</td>' +
          '</tr>' +
          '</table>'
        );
      }, 50);
      /*
      $.ajax({
        url: 'list.php',
        type: 'get',
        data: { 'slot': id, 'level': level, 'name': name },
        success: function(data) {
          $('#list').html(data);
        }
      });
      */
    }
    function hookUpId(id) {
      var timer = 0;

      $('#gearName').keyup(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
          showList(id);
        }, 300);
      });
    }    

    hookUpId('an-id');
  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The fact is that #gearName is changed by this ajax request. So, if I put it elsewhere, it doesn't work anymore. Also, the id is given by another function when you click on a specific div. So I don't really know how to get the id.

Comment: @loumi: *Changed* or *replaced*? If it's just *changed*, you don't have to hook it up again. If it's *replaced*, yes, that would mean you'd have to re-hook it. Seeing your HTML would help a lot.

Comment: It's replaced. I'll edit my question whith the html and the php relevant to this function in a minute.

Comment: @loumi: In the HTML you've put in your question, `gearName` is **not** inside `list`, and `list` is the only element you're updating. So `gearName` is *not* replaced. See above.

Comment: It's true. However, when I put it out of this function, it didn't work anymore. I put only an alert dialog inside the function and nothing happened when I entered values. It should be because the modal content code is loaded by modalContent(id).

Comment: @loumi: Most likely, it wasn't working because you were trying to hook it up before the element existed. Make sure the code is in a `script` tag at the *bottom* of the HTML (or executed **once** after loading the `#gearName` input, if that's done dynamically), so that the element exists as of when you're trying to hook it up. Hooking it up *every time* you call the function is definitely wrong, and very likely to be the problem (or **a** problem, anyway).

Comment: How can I execute it once after loading the page?

Comment: *"Make sure the code is in a `script` tag at the* bottom *of the HTML..."*

Comment: @loumi: If it is, and if `#gearName` is in the markup above, it then you **can** hook it up then. I've added a full example to the answer.